# OnClickListener doesn't change view in Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom BaseAdapter that row has some views in it.
Mainly a checkbox (ImageView) and button (ImageView) and hidden text (TextView).
Whenever I click on checkbox I want to change it's drawable and it seems to work, but only when I `notifyDataSetChanged` - which IMO shouldn't matter. If I remove the line then it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't work.
The more important part is that I want the button to show/hide `holder.expansion` but it doesn't work. Regardless `v.getTag()` I have also tried to use `holder.expansion`, but it didn't work either.

How can I get it to work? To change checkbox drawable and show/hide expansion text?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final DrugHolder holder;
    if (view == null)
    {
        holder = new DrugHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drug_list_row, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_name);
        holder.checkbox = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_checkbox);
        holder.arrow = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_arrow_button);
        holder.expansion = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_expansion);
        holder.fullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_full_name);
        holder.quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_quantity);
        holder.unitDose = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drug_list_unit_dose);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (DrugHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    Drug drug = allItems.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(drug.Name);
    holder.fullName.setText(drug.Name);
    holder.quantity.setText(String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%.2f", drug.Quantity));
    holder.unitDose.setText(drug.DoseType);
    holder.arrow.setTag(holder.expansion);

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            if (view.isSelected())
            {
                view.setSelected(false);
                view.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_unchecked));
            }
            else
            {
                view.setSelected(true);
                view.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_checked));
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    holder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) v.getTag();
            if (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

According to propositions of changes I have made this:

```
    if (drug.isChecked()) //Here breakpoint - enters only when entering activity
    {
        holder.checkbox.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_checked));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.checkbox.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_unchecked));
    }
    if (drug.isExpanded())
    {
        holder.fullName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.fullName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            drug.setChecked(!drug.isChecked()); // Breakpoint - enters when clicks
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // After F8 goes to this line but never goes to getView again
        }
    });

    holder.arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            drug.setExpanded(!drug.isExpanded()); // Breakpoint - enters when click
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // Never goes to this line after F8 - instead it jumps to View.java and shows red block with 'Source code does not match byte code
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save info in Drug about checked state and check this state when you set data into view. For example

```
if (drug.isChecked()) {
holder.checkbox.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_checked));
} else {
holder.checkbox.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_checkbox_unchecked));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should be inserted to set the CheckBox image in the ListView item. To set the CheckBox image after clicking, this should be inserted inside the onClick method and change to: drug.setChecked(!drug.isChecked()) and then the above code.

Comment: Same for showing expansion? In this case I should run notifyDataSetChanged(), right?

Comment: In listener you would setChecked in drug and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Isn't this too resourceful? Because I have to rerender whole list just to change one image. Could you make some explanation why my method doesn't work?

Comment: Your method change's icon in view, but when you call notify, all items rebind. In your bind method have not information about what state set in view. If you won't call notify this problem won't solved, because when you will scroll, views will rebind... Sry about my english ;)

Comment: It worked after I created `private DrugAdapter adapter = this;` and then called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`